# Unlinking objects from duplicated scene

Tags: light, scene

I have created a scene by duplicating another scene (using the Link Object Data option). I would now like to unlink some light sources. I have tried right-clicking them in the Outliner and clicking on Unlink, but it did not help - changing the strength of the light in the duplicated scene also changes the strength of the original light in the original scene. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is the following one:

Unlink in the *Outliner* will unlink the object from its Collection, not from its duplications.

A linked duplication is a complete other thing than an object linked to a collection. To link-duplicate an object (make a copy that will follow all the modifications on the original), you need to press <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> instead of <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>.

To unlink a duplication, i.e. make it single user that won't depend on its linked duplications, select your object, go to the header menu > *Object* > *Relations* > *Make Single User* > *Object & Data*, then select *Selected Object*.

The problem is that it will also unlink from the objects of the same scene (maybe there's a way not to but I don't know it).

[image]

Comment: I think this is just what I was looking for :) Many thanks, man!